# Get the next value within a sequence without using a generator function on click of a button with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, generator, sequence

What I want to achieve is to be able to get the next value (unique) within a factorialSequence on click of a button.

What I have done so far is to define a factorialSeq() function and a generator() function as shown below. The generator function takes the factorialSeq() as an argument. On click of a button, I was only able to receive the first value in the sequence, but if I log to the console, all the values in the sequence will be returned in the right order.

```
<button style="padding: 20px" id="nextBtn">Next</button>

<script>

    let nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');

    function generator(sequencer) {
        const seqArgs = [...arguments];
        seqArgs.shift();
        const seq = sequencer(...seqArgs);
        return {
            next() {
                return seq();
            }
        }
    }

    function factorialSeq() {
        let currentNumber = 1;
        let result;
        return function factorialReturn() {
            if (!result) {
                result = 1;
                return result;
            }

            result *= currentNumber;
            currentNumber += 1;
            return result;
        }
    }

    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var gen = generator(factorialSeq);

        console.log(gen.next());
        // console.log(gen.next());
        // console.log(gen.next());
        // console.log(gen.next());
    });
</script>
```

I expect the output to be different each time I click the button (i.e the next value in the sequence). Please note that I don't want to use the inbuilt generator function in javaScript. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On click of a button, I was only able to receive the first value in the sequence

That's because you are creating a new sequence  on every button click, and log only one value (the first). You'll want to do

```
var gen = generator(factorialSeq);
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(gen.next());
});
```

Comment: Oh my! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the following: You redefined generator on each click of `#next`. So use this instead:

```js
let nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');
let resetBtn = document.getElementById('resetBtn');

    function generator(sequencer) {
        const seqArgs = [...arguments];
        seqArgs.shift();
        const seq = sequencer(...seqArgs);
        return {
            next:()=>{
                return seq();
            }
        }
    }

    function factorialSeq() {
        let currentNumber = 1;
        let result;
        return function factorialReturn() {
            if (!result) {
                result = 1;
                return result;
            }

            result *= currentNumber;
            currentNumber += 1;
            return result;
        }
    }
    
    var gen = generator(factorialSeq);
    nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {

        console.log(gen.next());
    });
    resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        gen = generator(factorialSeq);
    });
```

```html
<button style="padding: 20px" id="nextBtn">Next</button>
<button style="padding: 20px" id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful